# Looking for a guide or book which would describe steps about working with *.wav (RIFF) files

Tags: c

I've found this site: [WAVE PCM soundfile format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) and had written a struct (the code is below). But I don't know no steps that I have to do to work with .wav files.

*I cannot find any book or guide which would describe steps about working with .wav (RIFF) files. And describe how to read-write (how to read RIFF header).*

I've written the following code, but now I'm at a dead-end:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char        Subchunk1ID[4];
    int         Subchunk1Size;
    short int   AudioFormat;
    short int   NumChannels;
    int         SampleRate;
    int         ByteRate;
    short int   BlockAlign;
    short int   BitsPerSample;

} fmt;

typedef struct
{
    char        Subchunk2ID[4];
    int         Subchunk2Size;
    int         Data[441000]; // 10 secs of garbage. he-he)
} data;

typedef struct
{
    char        ChunkId[4];
    int         ChunkSize;
    char        Format[4];
    fmt         SubChunk_fmt;
    data        SubChunk_data;
} header;



int main()
{
    FILE *input; 
    fopen("input.wav", "r");

    /* How to read the RIFF header, how to manipulate it
       and how to access and manipulate 'data' sub chunk? */

    return 0;
}
```

**P.S.**
I don't ask you to do some work instead of me, just give me some literature or links where I would be able to improve my knowledge on this subject.

Comment: What do you want to do with WAV files?  Are you unsure how to process the header?  Or the format of its audio data?

Comment: So you know how to use `fopen()` to open the file, but you don't know how to use `fread()` to read in chunks of the file for processing?

Comment: how to read something is a matter of ... well, reading. fread may be useful. Then, you have to take care of endianness and actual size of int, short int and so on. (Likely better you use int*_t, according to the need). Once you do that correctly, you can access your data through the "form" of the struct, and go ahead

Comment: Read this: http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/2010-10-14-Fun-with-wav/

Comment: @Elchonon Edelson, Yes, I don't know how to use fread() to read in chunks of the file for processing.

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately, your question seems to be too broad to easily answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be "I have a file format, how can I write a dissector for it in C". Given that you've stated that you don't know how to use `fread()`, my advice would be to look for a library that does it for you, such as libavcodec as mentioned by Filippo Savi. Otherwise, the question is too broad to be a fit for this site.

Writing a function to read in a file of known format is basically a lot of slog work. You have the file, which is a stream of bytes, you have the documentation, indicating, from the first byte on, exactly what you'll find, and how many bytes each thing holds. The work, then, involves reading everything in, one chunk at a time, and putting it into the appropriate place in your in-memory structure. (Or, if you really know what you're doing and are only interested in subsections, you can often use the knowledge of structure to read sizes and indexes, and then jump straight to some item in the middle that you want.)

The [fread()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/fread.html) function can be used to read things in one object at a time, or to read in a large chunk of data and process that in memory. The `fread()` function call looks like this: `fread(ptr, size, count, in)`, so if you had a file handle named `input`, obtained by calling, for example, `FILE *input = fopen("input.wav", "rb");`, and you have a buffer called `ptr`, obtained, for example, by `char *ptr = malloc(4096);`, you could read the first three 4-byte elements of the file (which, according to the document you linked, are a signature, a size calculation, and another signature,) by calling `fread(ptr, 4, 3, input)`. (You could also achieve the same goal by calling `fread(ptr, 12, 1, input);`, or `fread(ptr, 1, 12, input);`.)

This example *might* be enough to get you started, but if it isn't, then your question is "how do I do general file I/O and/or data manipulation in C", which I don't intend to try to answer. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me to get out of dead end.

Answer (score 1):

well knowing format and offsets should be trivial to get data out and place them in the structs using fread() so that you get binary data out of the file

then you need some sort of library if you want to play what you got out, but if you want to play sound I advice you to use a well tested codec library like libavcodec

P.S. you of course need to open the file first with fopen()